# POE phone: ethernet passthrough: is it transparent?

Tags: voip

I have a small sub-net in my office on a Netgear router. We're getting POE phones. If I plug the POE phone into the wall jack for its power and signal, will the phone pass  the ethernet data signal through 100% transparently to a router which is connected to the phone's PC jack?  As far as the router is concerned, will it "sense" something different or not know the difference when there's a POE phone between it and the wall jack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be transparent, ie the phone acts like a 2 port switch.